# Can you see what scripts are using the most CPU in Cpanel?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, cpu-usage, litespeed

I run a fairly active Wordpress blog and in the last 24 hours or so my CPU usage has been around 60 - 100%. My host claims not to be able to tell me what is causing these spikes but they tell me just to experiment with uninstalling various plugins.

Is there a way I can see the scripts that are causing this?

Comment: do you have root console access?

Comment: No, it's a shared hosting environment.

Comment: You are running a WordPress blog, which can be quite the heavyweight.  Are you sure you're not simply getting a boost in traffic as of late?

Comment: Then how do you know the CPU usage of an shared server, if you do not have console access? you using a custom script based on a function like `sys_getloadavg()` ? And have in mind, that on shared environment.. it ain't only use consuming resources.

Comment: @w0rldart I'm viewing CPU usage through Cpanel.

Comment: @JordanMeeter oh I see, and you sure it's YOUR cpu usage and not overall?

Comment: @w0ldart isn't that what Cpanel is supposed to reflect? it says my resources have been limited due to the high CPU usage...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the [P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/p3-profiler/) plugin to see which plugins are slowing down your WordPress site.

Comment: Will that accurately measure load on CPU though? That only seems to measure plugins that load in the web page... What if a plugin runs entirely in the background?